# Why is recursive solution faster than an iterative solution for this case?

Tags: c++, recursion, iteration, dynamic-programming

I am trying to obtain a solution for this question https://www.spoj.com/problems/COINS/.

But oddly enough, my iterative solution:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n;
    while(cin >> n){
        long long int dp[n+2];
        dp[0]=0;
        for(long long int i=1; i<=n; i++)
            dp[i]=max(dp[i/2]+dp[i/3]+dp[i/4], i);
        cout << dp[n] <<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

gets a TLE, while the recursive solution for this(Not mine) gets accepted in no time:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

map<int, long long> dp;

long long f(int n){
    if(n==0) return 0;

    if(dp[n]!=0) return dp[n];

    long long aux=f(n/2)+f(n/3)+f(n/4);

    if(aux>n) dp[n]=aux;
    else dp[n]=n;

    return dp[n];
}

int main(){    
    int n;

    while(scanf("%d",&n)==1) printf("%lld\n",f(n));

    return 0;
}
```

Shouldn't it be the opposite? I am genuinely confused.

Comment: Why do you use `cin` in the first example and `scanf` in the second? How can you expect to compare these two versions with such differences? Also which compiler, with which settings?

Comment: does not look like the loop solution is even correct. 1) it does not initialize 'dp', 2) it does not maximize values for fractions. i.e. i/2 can by itselve be split in 3 parts. Recursion does it, the loop does not.

Comment: where is the definition of the function: `max()`?

Comment: @user3629249 max() is an inbuilt c++ function.

Comment: @Serge the loop solution gives the correct answer. But it also shows a TLE.

Comment: suggest noting that the values in `dp[]` are calculated from `dp[0]` all the way to `dp[n]` in your recursive code, while the (quick) code only calculates those values that are of actual interest

Comment: OKAY yes, that would make sense.

Answer (score 0):

The iterative solution is linear in n i.e it's O(n) while the recursive one is O(log_2 n ) from what I can understand.